Does Map class in Dart really not have a retainWhere() method like List does?
It appears that while List and Set in Dart have both a removeWhere() method and a retainWhere() method (which just inverts the filter lambda function but is more readable), Map only seems to have a removeWhere() method. Is this intended or a weird oversight? I'm really confused by this.
Of course inverting the filter myself isn't really a problem or even writing my own extension to add the method myself, I can't seem to wrap my head around why those classes would have a mismatch like that.
Edit:
Here's the extension I wrote if anyone else wants to use it:
extension MapExtension<K, V> on Map<K, V> {
  void retainWhere(bool Function(K key, V value) test) {
    removeWhere((key, value) => !test(key, value));
  }
}


Yeah, I do was in the muddle, although looking at the Design Philosophy of these type i now do think Dart is quite right.
List is primarily designed for sequential, mutable data with lots of in-place modifications, so it includes methods like retainWhere for convenience.
Map, being more about key-value associations, often encourages creating new instances when performing such operations, which aligns with its primary use cases.

Hm, I think I would agree if not for the fact that both have removeWhere(). At this point there's really no harm in having both functions since other iterables have it.

It's simple enough:
final updated = {for (final e in input.entries) if (e.value > 5) e.key: e.value};

